# How to increment a string value number which is delimited by .'s (i.e 1.2.3 == 1.2.4)

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to update an string parameter and return another string with the updated version number.

Example input and output:

```
nextVersion("1.2.3") === "1.2.4";
nextVersion("0.9.9") === "1.0.0.";
nextVersion("1") === "2";
nextVersion("1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8") === "1.2.3.4.5.6.7.9";
nextVersion("9.9") === "10.0";
```

All numbers, except the first one, must not be greater than 10: if there are, you have to set them to 0 and increment the next number in sequence.

So far i can:
-Break the string apart
-Increment by One
-Put back together

I need help in identifying if a version number starts with 11.1 as when i increment it, it becomes 1.1.2 rather than 11.2

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string user_input;

        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        Console.WriteLine("Please input the version number to increment: ");
        user_input = Console.ReadLine();

        string new_version_number = next_Version(user_input);

        Console.WriteLine("Your number is : {0}", new_version_number);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

        public static string next_Version(string user_input)
    {

        //removing . for parsing
        string string_no_dots = user_input.Replace(".", "");

        //storing length to see if incrementing from version x99 to 100
        int string_length = string_no_dots.Length;

        //convert to int to increment version
        int number_no_dots;
        int.TryParse(string_no_dots,out number_no_dots);


        //increment by 1
        int new_version_number = number_no_dots+1;

        //convert back to string
        string new_version_string = Convert.ToString(new_version_number);

        //add the periods
        string string_with_dots = String.Join<char>(".", new_version_string);


        return string_with_dots;
    }
```

Input: 1.2.3.4

Output: 1.2.3.5   which is correct

but when

Input: 11.2.3

Output: 1.1.2.4  whereas the actual output should be 11.2.4

Thank you for your time

Comment: Have you considered leveraging the `Version` class instead of working on strings?

Comment: You should try splitting (string.split) the string into an array and add 1 to the last number of the array if the result is bigger than 9 then go to the previous number and repeat the process.

Comment: There's much that can be improved here, but not the point. Where is `All numbers, except the first one, must not be greater than 10` implemented at in your solution?

Comment: You already provided steps that your code should follow - " Break the string apart -Increment by One -Put back together" - why code you've posted does some crazy stuff like removing dots then? And where is the code to properly "increment by one" with carry? Not exactly sure what exact help you need *at this point* ...

Comment: Side note: while it is entertaining exercise please don't use that for actual versions - read something on "semantic versions" to see how version numbers are usually used.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov or leverage other classes/implementations that are available instead of *reinventing the wheel*... I think this may be an exercise or assignment?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb i will look into that class and see if it can help with what i am trying to accomplish

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i have no intention in using this for a versioning. as Çöđěxěŕ puts it, it is for an exercise.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if some enterprising student turned in work which used the right tool for the job, `System.Version` for instance.

Comment: @NatPongjardenlarp that would be unimaginable. We must have students build from scratch rather than use the tools that many have contributed towards its creation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this out:

```
public static string next_Version(string user_input)
{
    try
    {
        int[] values = user_input.Split(".".ToCharArray()).Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToArray();
        bool carryover;
        int index = values.Length - 1;
        do
        {
            carryover = false;
            values[index]++;
            if ((index > 0) && (values[index] == 10))
            {
                values[index] = 0;
                carryover = true;
                index--;
            }
        } while (carryover && (index >= 0));
        return String.Join(".", values);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return "[ Invalid Version Input! ]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't check to see if a number other than the first number was **already** greater than 10.  I'm only checking to see if it was exactly 10 after adding 1 to it.  If you want any number greater than 10 to reset to zero and only increment the next number by one, then change `== 10` to `>= 10`.

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to just check the original length of the string and compare it to the new one?
(To ensure that it can work for versions like 2.00.1)

Comment: @ivan I'm not understanding your comment.  Explain better and I can answer.

Comment: @ivan I see what you're saying.  It'll convert `00` to just `0`.  Not sure if that is a "bug" or a "feature" at this point as it wasn't covered in the specifications.

Comment: Yeah it wasn't specified but i was just asking if it would be just better overall to cover any cases.

(Anyhow your answer is fine and works for the case of the question).

Comment: @ivan What about this case? `2.    000    .     1       `.    The values inside can be converted to numbers, but should we keep the total length with the spaces included?

Comment: I would say that in 'that' specific case the string is malformed, and the whitespaces should be trimmed before doing anything (if they aren't already by converting them to numbers), or just to prevent that, turn them into numbers and get the length after turning them into numbers

Comment: @ivan But if only the first entry can go above 9, then all entries should only be a single digit.  Why would you have "00" in that second slot, if it can only be "1" to "9"?  Wouldn't that be malformed by your definition?

Comment: The '000' in the middle is automatically converted to '0' as soon as the string is made into a number, after it has been made into a number it should take into account its length

Comment: @ivan yes, but the length will only ever be ONE digit! ...unless it's the very first slot that can go over 9.

Comment: I see what you mean, in that case checking for length basically can be applied to more cases but for this one is just a slower answer

Comment: @Idle_Mind could you explain this portion

        int[] values = user_input.Split(".".ToCharArray()).Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToArray();

Comment: Sure. That first splits the version into a string array with String.Split(). Then,  from that resulting array, a LINQ query is performed with the Select() part.  That query passes each element from the string array through the [lambda expression](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) inside the Select() statement.  Each element is referenced with the "s" variable, which is passed into Convert.ToInt32().  This results in an enumerable collection of integers that is finally converted to an int array with ToArray().

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me i made it in a fiddle tested and working

[image: Fiddle screenshot]

Basically it just checks if the number's length (in characters) and if its bigger than the number + 1's length in characters then it converts it to a 0 and then adds the 1 to the following number, i should add 1 zero for each length the number had but this should work for your problem.

Edit: Nvm made it work for the case when many 0s are needed

IE: 1.99 == 2.00 instead of 1.99 == 2.0

Fiddle link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wvqHvu

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(next_Version("1.2.3.4"));
        Console.WriteLine(next_Version("11.2.3"));
    }
    public static string next_Version(string version)
    {
        string[] a = version.Split('.');
        int x = a.Length;
        int carrying = 1;
        while(x>0){

            int number = Convert.ToInt32(a[x-1]);

            if(Convert.ToString(number+carrying).Length > Convert.ToString(number).Length){
            string zeroes = "";
            foreach(char c in Convert.ToString(number)){
                zeroes += "0";
            }
            a[x-1] = zeroes;
            carrying = 1;
            }else{
                a[x-1] = Convert.ToString(number+carrying);
                carrying = 0;
                }
            x--;
        }
        String result = "";
        foreach(string s in a){
            result+=s+".";
        }

        return result.TrimEnd('.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest an approach like this:

```
string nextVersion(string user_input)
{
    var entries = user_input.Split('.')
                            .Select( s => int.Parse(s) )
                            .ToArray();

    void Inc(int index)
    {
        if ( index == 0 || ( entries[index] < 9 ) )
        {
            entries[index]++;
        }
        else
        {
            entries[index] = 0;
            Inc( index-1 );
        }
    }

    Inc( entries.Length-1 );

    return String.Join( ".", entries );
}
```

It splits the string into an array and converts each part into an int.  It then operates on the ints and then re-builds the version string from the int values.

Comment: It's a prettier, **recursive**, version of my submission.  Nicely done.

Comment: So it is.  I promise I hadn't seen your answer when I posted mine as you posted it while I was writing mine, but as they say:  Great minds think alike.

Comment: Lol...hope my comment didn't come off as angry or upset.  I like your submission!  =)

Comment: No, it didn't at all.  I took the "Prettier" and "Nicely done" parts to heart.  I just try to avoid posting duplicate answers, but it can't always be done.  :)